# AnyChart AreaChart gets doubled everytime I switch the tabs

Tags: android, anychart

I have implemented `AnyChart` in my app and I am using it on 3 different tabs, according to month, week and year. The problem it's that when the fragments are Created, I send a query to the server to return some values, to populate the chart. I have followed the steps according to the `github` of `AnyChart` to implement it and it works, but when I switch between the tabs, the `charts` gets doubled or even tripled.  I have implemented the same code for `AsyncTask` and `AnyChart` in all of the tabs, according to the number of days. I use the following code for the `charts`:

```
private void CreareGraficDinamicInterventie() {
    APIlib.getInstance().setActiveAnyChartView(anyChartView);
    Cartesian areaChart = AnyChart.area();

    areaChart.animation(true);

    Crosshair crosshair = areaChart.crosshair();
    crosshair.enabled(true);
    // TODO yStroke xStroke in crosshair
    crosshair.yStroke((Stroke) null, null, null, (String) null, (String) null)
            .xStroke("#fff", 1d, null, (String) null, (String) null)
            .zIndex(39d);
    crosshair.yLabel(0).enabled(false);

    areaChart.yScale().stackMode(ScaleStackMode.VALUE);

    List<DataEntry> seriesData = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j=data_grafic.size()-1  ; j>0 ; j-- ) {
        seriesData.add(new CustomDataEntry(String.valueOf(data_grafic.get(j)), Double.valueOf(timpi_interventie.get(j))));
    }



    ChartCredits credits = areaChart.credits();
    credits.enabled(false);
    Set set = Set.instantiate();
    set.data(seriesData);
    Mapping series1Data = set.mapAs("{ x: 'x' }");
    Area series1 = areaChart.area(series1Data);
    series1.name("Timp de interventie ");
    series1.stroke("3 #fff");
    series1.hovered().stroke("3 #fff");
    series1.hovered().markers().enabled(true);
    series1.hovered().markers()
            .type(MarkerType.CIRCLE)
            .size(4d)
            .stroke("1.5 #fff");
    series1.markers().zIndex(100d);

    areaChart.legend().enabled(true);
    areaChart.legend().fontSize(13d);
    areaChart.legend().padding(0d, 0d, 20d, 0d);

    areaChart.xAxis(0).title(false);
    areaChart.yAxis(0).title("Timp de interventie (h)");

    areaChart.interactivity().hoverMode(HoverMode.BY_X);
    areaChart.tooltip()

            .valuePostfix("h")
            .displayMode(TooltipDisplayMode.UNION);
    anyChartView.setChart(areaChart);
}
```

The `CreareGrafiDinamicInterventie()` gets called after the `onPostExecute` in the `AsyncTask` querying the server. I have tried to use `anyChartView.clear();` but the `chart` dissapears, it does not show anything. 
This is the `AsyncTask` called in `OnCreateView`:

```
private void GasesteDetaliiSaptamana(){
    class GasesteDetaliiSaptamana extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        User user = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getContext()).getUser();
        final String id_user = String.valueOf(user.getId());
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //creating request handler object
            RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

            //creating request parameters
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("interval_zile", "6");

            //returing the response
            return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(URLs.URL_STATISTICIGRAFICE, params);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //displaying the progress bar while user registers on the server
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            timpi_interventie.clear();
            timpi_rezolvare.clear();
            data_grafic.clear();
            //hiding the progressbar after completion
            try {
                //converting response to json object
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

                //if no error in response
                if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                    timp_raportare_rezolvare= obj.getString("timp_raportare_rezolvare");
                    timp_catalogare_rezolvare= obj.getString("timp_catalogare_rezolvare");
                    timp_raportare_catalogare= obj.getString("timp_raportare_catalogare");
                    numar_total_alerte_catalogate = obj.getString("numar_total_alerte_catalogate");
                    numar_alerte_remediate = obj.getString("numar_alerte_remediate");
                    numar_total_alerte = obj.getString("numar_total_alerte");
                    timp_mediu_interventie = obj.getString("timp_mediu_interventie");
                    timp_mediu_rezolvare = obj.getString("timp_mediu_rezolvare");
                    JSONArray rap_cat = obj.getJSONArray("vector_rap_cat");
                    for (int i = 0; i < rap_cat.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject Rap_cat = rap_cat.getJSONObject(i);
                        timpi_interventie.add(Rap_cat.getString("rap_cat"));
                    }
                    JSONArray rap_rez = obj.getJSONArray("vector_rap_rez");
                    for (int i = 0; i < rap_rez.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject Rap_rez = rap_rez.getJSONObject(i);
                        timpi_rezolvare.add(Rap_rez.getString("rap_rez"));
                    }
                    JSONArray data_alerte = obj.getJSONArray("data_alerte");
                    for (int i = 0; i < data_alerte.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject Data = data_alerte.getJSONObject(i);
                        data_grafic.add(Data.getString("data"));
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            CreareGraficDinamicInterventie();
        }
    }
    GasesteDetaliiSaptamana ru =new GasesteDetaliiSaptamana();
    ru.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way, and I will write it down, maybe in the future it will help others too. I have added in the `.xml` a `linear layout`, to where I want my chart to be:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/linear_chart"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
```

And, programically, I've created the `chart`, and added the `view` to this `layout`, removing all the `views` in the beginning.

```
 private void CreareGraficDinamicInterventie() {

    linear_chart.removeAllViews();
    AnyChartView anyChartView = new AnyChartView(getContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
    params.weight=1;
    anyChartView.setLayoutParams(params);
    Cartesian areaChart = AnyChart.area();
    ....
    anyChartView.setChart(areaChart);
    linear_chart.addView(anyChartView);
    }
```

Combine those with declaring the `LinearLayout` in `onCreate` and it should work, deleting the last `chart` and adding the new one.